# xcode gesture reconizer resize button

Tags: xcode

Hi i'm trying to drop a button on a uiview and make the button take on the size of the uiview .
I tried

```
button1.frame = drop3.frame; // drop3 is a uiview
```

but this just makes the button jump back to its original starting position and not change size.

this works sort of
the first time UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded it resizes then jumps back to it original position then it works fine?

```
 - (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
    {

         CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

            recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

         [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];


        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)

        {
            button1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2,2);

        self.button1.center = drop3.center;
        }
```

Comment: Guess, you are setting `UIButton` frame after that function gets called.

Comment: isn't the transform after the UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded stops thou? weird how it works after the first time